# How to achieve the same function as the following code using Clojure?

Tags: python, clojure, common-lisp

In fact this is a question in http://www.paulgraham.com/icad.html
Common Lisp code:

```
(defun foo (n)
　　(lambda (i) (incf n i)))
```

Python code:

```
def foo (n):
    s = [n]
    def bar (i):
        s[0] += i
        return s[0]
    return bar
```

I wonder how to save a value in a function using Clojure.

Note that this is an accumulator, which means

```
(def foo-2 (foo 2))
(foo 2) => 4
(foo 3) => 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (defn foo [n]
   (let [accumulate (atom n)]
     (fn [i] (swap! accumulate + i))))

 (def foo-2 (foo 2))

 (foo-2 2)
 => 4
 (foo-2 3)
 => 7
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do this. Please take a look at the description of the question, thanks!

Comment: @XiangruLian updated

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want!